# Parsing the contents of a file in a github repository without cloning it?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to parse the contents of a file in a github repository without having to clone it first. I have been scouring through the JavaScript github API documentation and having trouble figuring out how to do this without having first cloned its contents.

Comment: If you go to the raw version of one of the source files, github should send you to a page starting with `https://raw.githubusercontent.com`.  You should be able to make an ajax request to that file.  I've done something similar with making jsfiddle snippets reference github files.

Comment: Does the ajax request approach allow all CORS origins? It would be something to consider if you need to supply credentials or an API token with your request vs. an anonymous request.

Comment: My usage, in the least, did not have CORS issues simply making the ajax request to that resource directly like that.  No tokens or anything special.  Just a simple GET request.  @CameronTinker

Comment: For my purposes, i am getting content from an open gitup project, so auth may not be a factor here. But it looks like that will work

Comment: however, I would benefit from being able to first parse all files in this `<repo>` that contain `*<text>*` in filename, then parse only the content from those files.

Comment: @Taplar what I'm thinking atm is perhaps list files in repo => parse repo_contents for `*<text>*` in filename => take filenames with `<text>` and append it to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/x/y/z/` => then parse contents of file :) .. idk if that's the best way I can do that though.